# How do you configure Apache Ivy to remove orphan artifacts?

Tags: java, ant, ivy

Let's say I have an `ivy.xml` that contains the following:

```
  <dependency org="checkstyle" name="checkstyle" rev="4.3" />
```

And then I want to upgrade to Checkstyle 4.4, so I change my `ivy.xml` to contain:

```
  <dependency org="checkstyle" name="checkstyle" rev="4.4" />
```

After a `retrieve` with the first configuration, I have the file `checkstyle-4.3.jar`. After the second configuration, I also have the file `checkstyle-4.4.jar`, and the file `checkstyle-4.3.jar` still exists.

Is there a way to have Ivy realize that the old file is an orphan, and remove it from the `lib` directory? The idea is that I don't want my developers' disk space usage to drastically increase every time I upgrade a tool.

Ideally I'd also want it removed from the local repository as well. I do realize that the intent of the local repository is that it is shared among projects, so it would not make sense to remove anything, as it would not know if the artifact was still in use in other projects. But there must be some kind of prune procedure...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been using Ivy 2.0.0, so I don't know if this applies to the version you're using.

The Ivy [`retrieve`](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/use/retrieve.html) task has a `sync` attribute. Set this to `true` and unused/unknown files in your retrieved directory (`lib` in your case) will be removed. Keep in mind this will mean *any* manually copied artifacts in this directory which Ivy doesn't specifically resolve will be removed.

Also, note that if you use the `sync` option but Ivy resolves no dependencies (empty or missing `ivy.xml`, for example), the retrieve directory will be deleted.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! By the way, I'm using 2.1.0-RC1.

Comment: By the way, I've determined that this does not remove the items from the cache. Therefore the benefit is that you won't have multiple versions of the same jar in your lib directory (which is important), but you won't save much disk space. An occasional ivy:cleancache will do that job.